# How to hide a button based on a returning value in success handler?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm new to Jquery. I have a code like this :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "${createLink(controller :"
    tasks ", action :"
    holidayStatus ")}",

    data: "userName=" + $("#user").find('option:selected').text() + "&date1=" + $("#datePicker").val() + "&date2=" + $("#datePicker2").val(),
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
        $(".errors").append(html);
        $(".errors").delay(1000).fadeIn('slow');
        $("#createButton").delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
    })​
```

This works as expected. In my `success` handler, I'm appending the `html` (which I got from server-side) to the `.errors` class. At the same time I'm hiding the button with id `createButton`.

But what I want is a way to find whether `html` in `success` handler contains any data (there are chances that `html` doesn't have any *content* in it). If so I need to disable the `createButton` id if not I shouldn't do anything.

How to proceed with it?

Comment: @binarious. he marked the **content** word... _"(there are chances that html doesn't have any **content** in it)"_

Comment: @gdoron when there is no content, the string should be empty, shouldn't it?

Comment: nope i.e. "<p></p>" is not empty, which is btw kinda ugly to have such an ajax response anyway

Comment: @mightyuhu. [it's empty](http://jsfiddle.net/u3U6d/1). unlike ` "<p>foo </p>"` (I might not understood what you meant.)

Comment: @gdoron he meant the string. But yes, you're right. I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($(html).contents().length) // there is content in html
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/u3U6d/1/)

Comment: Clean and expressive! +1 Thanks for the live demo

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `html` is a string you could simply check for a `html.legth > 0`.

```
success: function(html) {
    if (html.length > 0) {
        $(".errors").append(html);
        $(".errors").delay(1000).fadeIn('slow');
        $("#createButton").delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
    }
})
```

Comment: thats not what hes looking for could be empty containersets

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "${createLink(controller :"tasks", action :"holidayStatus")}",
  data: "userName=" + $("#user").find('option:selected').text() + "&date1=" 
                    + $("#datePicker").val() + "&date2=" 
                    + $("#datePicker2").val(),
  cache: false,
  success: function(html) {
           if(html)
           {
               $(".errors").append(html);
               $(".errors").delay(1000).fadeIn('slow');
               $("#createButton").delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
               $("#createButton").removeAttr('disabled'); //remove disabled
           }else{
               $("#createButton").attr('disabled','disabled'); //disable button                   
           }                     
})
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

**dataTypeString**
Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)
The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response.

**"html"**: Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM.

```
//"html" is a string, so simple take it length
if(html.length > 0) {
  $(".errors").append(html);
  $(".errors").delay(1000).fadeIn('slow');
  $("#createButton").delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');  
}
```